How to center a wrap div when justify-content: left
I'd like to visually center .projects__content div while keeping the cards aligned on the left: screenshot
I understand that a wrapped div calculates its width also including gaps when a line isn't perfectly filled, but I'd like to find a solution so that this isn't the case.
Maybe I'm missing something - it's a seemingly simple problem, but I can't seem to solve it.
Here is my code:
<section id="projects">
    <h2>Mes projets</h2>
    <div class="projects__content">
        <div class="card card3d archived">
            <div class="card__image">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200" alt="Site web">
            </div>

            <div class="card__content">
                <h3>Site web</h3>
                <p>Site web réalisé avec HTML, CSS et JavaScript.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card card3d archived" ...>
        <div class="card card3d archived" ...>
        <div class="card card3d archived" ...>
        <div class="card card3d archived" ...>
    </div>
</section>

#projects {
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.projects__content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 1em;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    --card-width: 16em;
    --card-padding: calc(.025 * var(--card-width));

    width: var(--card-width);
    aspect-ratio: 7/10;
    padding: var(--card-padding);
    border-radius: calc(.03 * var(--card-width));
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    transition: transform .4s ease-out, box-shadow .4s ease-out;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    box-shadow: 0 .25em .75em rgba(17, 12, 46, .1);
}

I've already tried centering the .projects__content div with its parent #project using flex in almost every possible way.

Try adding justify-items: center in .projects__content
